# How to properly connect to external service via native library in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-bean

Working in Spring Boot and want to use native library in order to connect to and use external storage system. I downloaded JAR file and dll files, imported JAR via Maven. Now I want to create Bean that will serve as @Service with basic functionalities: upload, download, etc.

So it looks like this:

```
@Service
public class StorageSystemClient {

  private NativeLibrary nativeLibrary;

  public StorageSystemClient() {
    String url = "...";
    this.nativeLibrary = NativeLibraryConnector.connect(url);
  }

  public File downloadFile(String filename) {
    return this.nativeLibrary.download(filename);
  }

}
```

**Problem:** What I don't like here is connecting process in `StorageSystemClient` constructor.

**Question:** What should be proper way to perform this connection once, in bean initializing phase for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that the fact that you're working with native library matters here.

Is for the solution I recommend excluding the connection logic from `StorageSystemClient` and letting spring deal with it. This way the `StorageSystemClient` will become unit testable and clear in general.

The `NativeLibrary` will become managed by spring.

You might end up with the following code:

```
@Configuration
public void NativeLibraryConfig {
   @Bean
   public NativeLibrary nativeLibrary() {
     String url = "..."; // can be externalized to configuration, or whatever you need,
     // in any case StorageSystemClient should not resolve the url by itself
     return NativeLibraryConnector.connect(url);
   }
}

@Service
public class StorageSystemClient {

  private NativeLibrary nativeLibrary;

  public StorageSystemClient(NativeLibrary nativeLibrary) {
    this.nativeLibrary = nativeLibrary;
  }

  public File downloadFile(String filename) {
    return this.nativeLibrary.download(filename);
  }
}
```

Comment: I like the solution since connecting process is done while initializing bean outside of client. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use `PostConstruct`, with something like

```
  @PostConstruct
  private void init() {
    //establish connection 
  }
```

It's made exactly for running initialization code once, after the bean construction.

Answer (score 1):

Just use dependency injection. The `NativeLibraryConnector.connect(url);` is just a factory method.

```java
@Bean
public NativeLibrary nativeLibrary(String url) {
  return NativeLibraryConnector.connect(url);
}
```

```java
@Service
public class StorageSystemClient {

  private final NativeLibrary nativeLibrary;

  public StorageSystemClient(NativeLibrary nativeLibrary) {
    this.nativeLibrary = this.nativeLibrary;
  }

  public File downloadFile(String filename) {
    return this.nativeLibrary.download(filename);
  }

}
```